# VUE.js records undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am creating an application where I have a list of users, when I click on a single user, it takes me to that specific users profile (Profile.vue). I am using ASP.NET Core API with Vue.js as my front end. My API is working so when I click on the user, I am able to see the data coming from my database using Chrome dev Tools and Postman. When I open Vue Dev Tools in Chrome, I see that the data is "undefined". For example, I am just trying to get the users firstName to display so I know that its working.

[image: attached]

This is how I am routing my page from the list of users to a specific users profile

```
 methods: {
      editItem(lastName) {
        this.$http.get(`http://localhost:61601/api/GetInquiry/${lastName}`)
        this.$router.push({ path: `/Profile/${lastName}` }) 
      },
      async GetAllInquiries() {
        this.loading = true

        try {
          this.records = await api.GetAllInquiries()
        } finally {
          this.loading = false
        }
      },
```

Once I am routed, Here is my Profile.Vue that will show the users information

```
<template>
  <div>
        <h2>Student Info</h2>
        Student Name: {{ records.firstName }}
        <br />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import api from '../store/api.js'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        records: {
          firstName: this.firstName
        },
      }
    },
    async created() {
      this.GetInquiriesByUser()
    },
    methods: {
      async GetInquiriesByUser() {
        this.loading = true
      },
      post: function () {
        this.$http.get('http://localhost:61601/api/inquiry', {
          firstName: this.firstName
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

API.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:61601/api/',
  json: true
})

export default {
  async execute(method, resource, data) {
    return client({
      method,
      url: resource,
      data,
    }).then(req => {
      return req.data
    })
  },
  GetAllInquiries() {
    return this.execute('get', '/Inquiry')
  },
  GetInquiriesByUser() {
    return this.execute('get', '/GetInquiry/')
  },
  create(data) {
    return this.execute('post', '/', data)
  },
  update(id, data) {
    return this.execute('put', `/${id}`, data)
  },
  delete(id) {
    return this.execute('delete', `/${id}`)
  }
}
```

GetInquiryByUser Controller

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class GetInquiryController : BaseController
    {
        private GetInquiryByUser manager;
        public GetInquiryController(IConfiguration config) : base(config)
        {
            manager = new GetInquiryByUser(config);
        }

        [HttpGet("{lastName}")] //api/GetInquiry/yourlastname
        public IEnumerable<InquiryModel> Get([FromRoute]string lastName)
        {
            return manager.GetInquiriesByUser(lastName);
        }
    }
```

The Inquiry contoller gets the list of all users and my GetInquiryByUser is passing the lastName to get that specific users profile. (eventually I will pass a unique id, just testing for now)
I am using hash mode for vue routing as well. At first I was confused on what mode I was using and I had a combination of history and hash, but I think I am all hash mode now. 
If someone can point me into the right directions, that would be awesome! Please let me know if I need to porvide more details.

Comment: why are you doing `data() {
      return {
        records: {
          firstName: this.firstName
        },
      }
    }`

Comment: I removed that, still does not work, I was looking around stackoverflow and someone had something like that, so i tried it. @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: so could you explain what's your use case in the `profile` component?

Comment: I have a list of users and I want to create a profile for them with that shows me their first name, last name, address, etc. I can already see the results in dev tools in chrome and Postman and using breakpoints in VS, so i know my API is begin called. I just cant seem to display the results on the browser. So far, I just want to display the users firstName so I know that its working, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The profile component should be talking to my GetInquiryController, which has my GetInquiriesByUser method. I hope this makes sense. @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: i'm not familiar with `async` and `await` but i think that you want to do something like `this.$http.get('http://localhost:61601/api/inquiry').then(resp=>this.first_name=resp.data.first_name;)` inside `created` lifecycle hook